# yasnippet not working on org

Tags: yasnippet

I created such a snippet

```
$ cat snippets/diary_template 
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: diary template
# key: dt
# condition: t    
# --

**** Personal_Notes
**** Personal_Tasks
**** Project_Notes
**** Project_Tasks(base)
```

set yas-snippet-dirs as

```
;;yasnippet
(require 'yasnippet)
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.doom.d/snippets"                 ;; personal snippets
        ))

(yas-global-mode 1) ;;
```

Reload the config file and activate the  yas-minor mode

In the `sdiary.org` input `dt` and strike `dt`. nothing happened.

What's the problem with my operations?

Comment: Hmm, this may require some more debugging. Is the snippet listed in the tables if you run: `yas-describe-tables`?

Comment: No, it is not listed. @Xaldew

Comment: Okay, then we know that `yas` hasn't indexed the snippet for some reason. Can you try to run `yas-reload-all` followed by `yas-describe-tables`? It may also be worth trying to use a canonicalized path in `yas-snippet-dirs` (i.e., remove the tilde).

Comment: ty, it working, amazing. @Xaldew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the snippet into a folder with the name of the mode to use it in as follows:

`snippets/org-mode/diary_template`

Check out the documentation:

[Organizing snippets > Basic structure](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html#org91b0471):

```
.
|-- c-mode
|   `-- printf
|-- java-mode
|   `-- println
`-- text-mode
    |-- email
    `-- time
```

[Expanding snippets > ... > Eligible snippets](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#orga555023) :

> YASnippet does quite a bit of filtering to find out which snippets are eligible for expanding at the current cursor position.
>
> In particular, the following things matter:
>
> - Currently loaded snippets tables
>
>   These are loaded from a directory hierarchy in your file system. See Organizing Snippets. They are named after major modes like html-mode, ruby-mode, etc…
> - Major mode of the current buffer
>
>   If the currrent major mode matches one of the loaded snippet tables, then all that table's snippets are considered for expansion. Use M-x describe-variable RET major-mode RET to find out which major mode you are in currently.
>
> ...